# Change the foreground color of a TextBlock in the LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textblock, foreground, longlistselector

I have a longlistselector for my windows phone 8 app:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="AppMenuList" Background="Transparent"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AppMenuListTemplate}"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="true" HideEmptyGroups="true"
                        LayoutMode="List" SelectionChanged="OnMenuItemTapped"
                        Margin="5,50,0,0"/>
```

With the following `DataTemplate`:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AppMenuListTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="80" Width="800" Tap="vTapFeedback">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,20,0,20" Height="50"
                           Width="800" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                           Text="{Binding MenuItemName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="32" Foreground="#115445" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

From my C# code, I am setting the `ItemsSource` property for the longlistselector to display the list of items to the user. However all the items are of same color as specified in the `TextBlock` property `Foreground`.

I have a requirement in which I want the user to be able to tap every item of the list and perform some operation except the one. I want that it should be shown as disabled to the user by using a Gray color for it.

I am not able to accomplish this. Can anyone suggest how I can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are three solutions that come to my mind:

- you can use VisualTreeHelper to find your textbox and then change its Foreground Color
- I've bound Foreground color to a property of Item Class, then when I change this property, Foreground changes automatically. I assume than you were able to bind your Text, then there should be no problem with binding Foreground. One thing you will probably need is a Converter.
- you can define VisualStates in Style of your TextBlock.

**EDIT** - code sample after request
I've definded my Converter like this:

```
namespace myApp.Converters
{
   public class BoolToBrush : IValueConverter
   {
    private Brush FalseValue = (Application.Current.Resources["TransparentBrush"] as Brush);
    private Brush TrueValue = (Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as Brush);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return FalseValue;
        else
            return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
    }
 }
```

In my Item class I've a property Selected (bool in this case) to which Foreground (or Background) is bound. I use it in XAML (item or control) like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myApp.Converters">
    <local:BoolToBrush x:Key="boolToBrush"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Name="myElement" Background="{Binding Path=Selected, Converter={StaticResource boolToBrush}}">
```

Of course you can define more coplex convertes - if you need more Brushes and so on.
On the other hand I would also consider using VisualStates.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: I also tried to bind the Foreground to a property on the item class, but i was unsuccessful to do that. Can you please help me to accomplish this using `Converter` class as suggested by you.